# express post request can not find body and it's contentes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, fetch

Here is my javascript code:

```js
 const handleClick = () => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("desc", value);
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/notes/create", {
      method: "POST",
      body: fd,
    }).then((res) => {
      alert(result);
    });
  };
```

The express server code:

```js
app.post("/notes/create", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

Here is the api request result:

[image]

And this is in my terminal:

[image]

I had a hope that on calling the function above will log the `body` object to the console, but this is not happening.

Note: I have already tried adding `app.use(express.json())`, but it doesn't work for me either.
If you are reading this without thinking TLDR; Thank you for your patience. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the test handleClick add:

```
headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```

It should look like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/notes/create", {
  method: "POST",
  body: fd,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

**Edit:** Sorry, you are **not trying to send a JSON**
**You are trying to send a file**, you are trying to send a file, for that you will need a library like express-fileupload (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) or formidable (https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) , there are more

Comment: Actually I want to send formData(text-only) but it doesn't work. Thank you for your answer.